# Pass one command output to other command

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I wanted to extract column 3 through `awk '{print $3}' mysql` and add `command[column 3 output]=` at start of that file(mysql) and so on.
I am unable to do it using sed:

```
sed "s/^/command[$(awk '{print $3}' mysql)]=/" mysql
```

File Content:

```
/usr/local/check_abc -a Handler_read_rnd -A Handler_read_rnd -w ">49000000" -c ">50000000"
/usr/local/check_abc -a Handler_delete -A Handler_delete -w ">520000" -c ">530000"
```

Output Should be like:

```
command[Handler_read_rnd]=/usr/local/check_abc -a Handler_read_rnd -A Handler_read_rnd -w ">49000000" -c ">50000000"
command[Handler_delete]=/usr/local/check_abc -a Handler_delete -A Handler_delete -w ">520000" -c ">530000"
```

How can I make that command work?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `awk`:

```
awk '{print "command[" $3 "]=" $0}' mysql.txt
```

Explanation:

`$0` is a special variable it contains the whole line of input. `$1` - `$xxx`  contain the fields in the input. `$3` is field 3.

Output:

```
command[Handler_read_rnd]=/usr/local/check_abc -a Handler_read_rnd -A Handler_read_rnd -w ">49000000" -c ">50000000"
command[Handler_delete]=/usr/local/check_abc -a Handler_delete -A Handler_delete -w ">520000" -c ">530000"
```

Comment: Great! It's working. Could you elaborate a little bit.

Comment: Much better! Thank you @EdMorton

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple search ended up with me finding this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pass-the-output-of-previous-command-to-next-as-an-argument

I quote:

> To answer your question, it sounds like you want to capture the rate
>   from the output of the first command, and then use the rate as a
>   command line argument for the second command. Here's one way to do
>   that:

```
rate=$(command1 | sed -ne 's/^rate..\([0-9]*\)%.*/\1/p')
command2 -t "rate was $rate"
```

check out that page for more info if this doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\S+)(\s+)?){3}/command[\2]=&/' file
```

Match the first three arguments of each line and using pattern matching and grouping manufacture the required string.

N.B. Iterations of groups within groups always remember the last match.